# SalesForce: Classic to Lighting

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Apologies if my question my be so dumb but my programming skills are really limited and I'm on a hurry for a PoC.

I have the apex class below which was developed for Classic. I would like to make it work with lighting and I'm not sure if the only thing I need to replace are the url's. I have created a developer account for my PoC and everytime I launch the class I'm redirected to Classic.

```
public class LookupByUrlParamController {

    String accountName;
    String accountNumber;
    String phone;
    String website;
    String email;
    String socialhandle;
    
    public LookupByUrlParamController () { }

    public String redirectToAccount() {
        
        Account account;
        
        Map<String,String> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        if(params.size() > 0) {
            accountName = params.get('account_name');
            accountNumber = params.get('account_number');
            phone = params.get('phone');   
            website =  params.get('website');   
            email =  params.get('email');
            socialhandle =  params.get('SocialHandle');
        }
        
        try {
            if(accountName != null) {
                account = [select ID from Account where name = :accountName limit 1];   
            } 
        } catch (System.queryException e) {//no entry found for lookup item, display empty account page
            return 'https://na7.salesforce.com/001/e';
        }    
          
        try {
            if(accountNumber != null) {
                account = [select ID from Account where AccountNumber = :accountNumber limit 1];   
            }
         } catch (System.queryException e) {//no entry found for lookup item, display empty account page
            return 'https://na7.salesforce.com/001/e';
         }   
            
        try {
             if(phone != null) {
                
                String npa;
                String nnx;
                String extension;
        
                //  Added logic for NA phone numbers

                if (phone.length() == 10) {
                    npa = phone.substring(0,3);
                    nnx = phone.substring(3,6);
                    extension = phone.substring(6,10);
                    phone = '(' + npa + ') ' + nnx + '-' + extension;
                }

                account = [select ID from Account where phone = :phone limit 1]; 
             }
        } catch (System.queryException e) {//no entry found for lookup item, display empty account page
            return 'https://na7.salesforce.com/001/e';
        }        
            
        try {     
             if(website != null) {
                account = [select ID from Account where website = :website limit 1]; 
             }
         } catch (System.queryException e) {//no entry found for lookup item, display empty account page
            return 'https://na7.salesforce.com/001/e';
         }       
            
         try {
              if(email != null) {
                account = [select ID from Account where email__c = :email limit 1]; 
              }
         } catch (System.queryException e) {//no entry found for lookup item, display empty account page
             return 'https://na7.salesforce.com/001/e';
         }   
             
         try {
              if(socialhandle != null) {
                account = [select ID from Account where SocialHandle__c = :socialhandle limit 1]; 
              }
         } catch (System.queryException e) {//no entry found for twitter handle lookup item, display empty account page
             return 'https://na7.salesforce.com/001/e';
         }      
       
        
        String accountUrl;
        if(account != null) {
            accountUrl = '/' + account.Id;
        } else {
            accountUrl = '/';
        }
        
        return accountUrl;
    }   

    public static testMethod void testLookupByUrlParamAccount() {
        LookupByUrlParamController controller = new LookupByUrlParamController();
        controller.accountName = 'Avaya';
        String redirectUrl = controller.redirectToAccount();
        System.assertEquals(redirectUrl, '/001A0000007UkkFIAS');
    }
    
    public static testMethod void testLookupByUrlParamInvalidAccount() {
        LookupByUrlParamController controller = new LookupByUrlParamController();
        controller.accountName = '';
        String redirectUrl = controller.redirectToAccount();
        System.assertEquals(redirectUrl, 'https://na7.salesforce.com/001/e');
    }
    
    public static testMethod void testLookupByUrlParamPhone() {
        LookupByUrlParamController controller = new LookupByUrlParamController();
        controller.phone = '1234';
        String redirectUrl = controller.redirectToAccount();
        System.assertEquals(redirectUrl, '/001A0000007UkkFIAS');
    }
    
     public static testMethod void testLookupByUrlParamWherePhoneNumberIs10Chars() {
        LookupByUrlParamController controller = new LookupByUrlParamController();
        controller.phone = '1234567891';
        String redirectUrl = controller.redirectToAccount();
        System.assertEquals(redirectUrl, 'https://na7.salesforce.com/001/e');//no record found
       
    }
    
    public static testMethod void testLookupByUrlParamInvalidPhoneNumber() {
        LookupByUrlParamController controller = new LookupByUrlParamController();
        controller.phone = '';
        String redirectUrl = controller.redirectToAccount();
        System.assertEquals(redirectUrl, '/001A0000015EKVPIA4');
        
    }
    
    public static testMethod void testLookupByUrlParamAccountNumber() {
        LookupByUrlParamController controller = new LookupByUrlParamController();
        controller.accountNumber = '4321';
        String redirectUrl = controller.redirectToAccount();
        System.assertEquals(redirectUrl, '/001A0000007UkkFIAS');
    }
    
    public static testMethod void testLookupByUrlParam() {
        LookupByUrlParamController controller = new LookupByUrlParamController();
        String redirectUrl = controller.redirectToAccount();
        System.assertEquals(redirectUrl, '/');
    }
    
}
```

In addition if anyone can tell where to being looking in the documentation to simply launch to new customer record form, or what are the redirect URLS?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you mean by

> everytime I launch the class I'm redirected to Classic

However, this code appears not to have been touched in quite a number of years and there's several things you ought to change.

1. You are hard-coding non-My Domain Salesforce instance URLs (`na7.salesforce.com`). You should instead use `URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()`, and you'll need to turn on My Domain sooner or later.
2. You are using Classic-format URLs, which still work but will result in additional redirects. The Lightning equivalent for the "Create new Account" URL is `lightning/o/Account/new` and for a specific record is `lightning/r/Account/<Id>/view`. When you build Lightning components, you can use the navigation service to get these URLs dynamically.
3. You have inline test methods, which haven't been allowed since an API version well before I started on the platform. Break those out into a separate test class.

Comment: David thanks for the information. I'm aware the code is really old, and I know I will have to make some tweaks. You have now provided a starting point for me to begin my PoC. I'm not a real programmer but I can do basic things with support like yours. The comments in point 2. Where I can find this info? Thanks

Comment: I don't know that it's officially documented, but you can easily observe it just by interacting with the Lightning UI.